# Near field acoustics

Tags: energy, particle-physics, waves

How much difference (in dB) is approximately between a broadband impulse noise which is mistakenly calculated back to a near field distance and a measurement, which considers the near field?
For example: 
A noise is measured in 2m distance with 80dB and then it is calculated back to 118dB at 0.025m.
Or: The same noise, but the near field characteristics are included in the measurement.
What is the approximately decibel difference between those measurements?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has no definite answer. The beauty of the far field lies within the fact, that you don't need a very rich knowledge about the geometry of the object you're surveying.

In the picture you provided the sound source seems to be some kind of engine. Parts of the engine are especially loud, some parts do not contribute to the overall noise level. Different parts may also have different resonance/vibration patterns, and therefore sound differently.

Your near field measurement has a very high dependency, of where exactly the microphone is placed. Along the exhaust pipes I expect higher values, but the away-facing side of the engines flywheel may even be a bit quieter than expected.

So there is no "approximate difference" between far field extrapolation and near field measurements, as it's not even clear, whether this would result in a positive or negative difference.

Comment: So, do you think, that the calculation from the free field back to the near field is a good estimation?

Comment: It's a good estimate for the *average* of the near field. But if you have a very heterogenious machinery, your location based variation around this average will be very large.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Just one more thing. You said that the difference can be positive (more decibels than measured) and negative (less decibels than measured). Why can it be also negative?

Comment: As stated in the answer: If you put your microphone next to one of the major emission points (like an exhaust, or where parts are rattling against each other) you expect to measure a higher value than what your far field extrapolation predicts. But if you place the mic somewhere down near the massive support structure and the rubber damping elements where the machine rests upon, you have a good chance, that it will be a bit quieter compared to the far field calculation.

Comment: Ah ok. The thing is, that this machine is only an example. My measurement was made in order to measure a slap on a dummy face (not a human) in combat sports. So what do you expect there? How much decibels is the difference approximately (your estimation)?

Comment: My estimation - well I won't (as I can't) give you any numbers. But same rationale applies here: Putting the mic along the skin, right next to the slap, will yield high values. Mic at the opposite side of the head will yield low values. But if you hit the dummy's ear, and you are interested, whether his eardrum is in any danger, let me tell you: It is. Additional to any sound wave, your palm forces the air inside his ear, suddenly increasing  the static pressure a lot. Additionally, your opponent's muscles are tense, awaiting the blow, hindering pressure equilibration.

Comment: It's not about the eardrum (it is of course in danger). It's about the sound pressure which can harm the inner ear.

Comment: I thought of a deviation of 5dB approximately

Comment: If you are really interested in inner ear injury, that's something very different. If the ear is not directly hit, the shock/accelerations and possibly a fracture  in the area of the tempural bone are a great danger to the inner ear. And if the ear suffers the direct blow, you create a sealed compartment with an abrupt rise of static pressure, which is it's own case. So the sound, as in "the stuff that travels to the far field", would not be my main concern. If it was about the ear of a second person, right next to your victim, we would be back to sound waves.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it was not measured directly on the ear, but rather at the cheek near the ear. So don't consider static pressure. It's a weak slap, which is only for the moment of surprise. So there is no fracture to consider.

Comment: So, what do you think?

Comment: As I already stated: I won't give you a number, as I can't. But I'd be happy to hear back from you, after you made the measurements. Either way, my recollections of my schooldays seem to suggest that weak slaps on the cheek usually don't result in extended damage to the inner ear.

Comment: Ok. So all in all, can I use the distance law for an average estimation for this or not?

Comment: *Of course*, you *can* use it. Use it for a first estimate, to get an idea, what the numbers could look like. But keep in mind, that you abuse a far field approximation in areas, where it's not expected to work. Before doing anything meaningful (hitting your colleague, because numbers say it's safe), you should consider further investigation. You can do your own measurements, or you can dive into literature. I'm sure there are plenty of medical studies covering the hot topic of slap-related inner ear injuries.